# Program AOSP Launcher3 to hide specific app

Tags: java, android

I've tried to hide app from launcher by adding and changing codes form the app source but failed every time.

Is it possible to hide a specific app from the launcher by editing Launcher3 source code? btw I'm working with AOSP build and want to integrate a 3rd party Open Source app into Settings, so that it can only be opened from Settings.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to remove the `LAUNCHER` `<intent-filter>` from the open source app?

Comment: Minor spelling corrections.

Comment: tried it... but couldn't start `MainActivity`

Answer (score 2):

Looking through the original Launcher3 source code, you will find `AppFilter` file under `/src/com/android/launcher3`. From the file name itself, we know it’s a class to filter applications. There is a method called `shouldShowApp`, as its name suggest, is to consider if an application is needed to show.

Following this, `AllAppsList.java` uses this method in the add method. Clearly, when `mAppFilter.shouldShowApp` return false, it will return directly, making the applications to exclude from the application list, which will not be displayed.

Thus,
The easiest way is by simply change Line the line in `AppFilter.java` to be `return !"com.google.android.gm".equals(app.getPackageName());`, where this snippet of code will make sure that the package “`com.google.android.gm`” (Gmail) to be excluded from showing up in Launcher.

```
package com.android.launcher3;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;

public class AppFilter {

    public static AppFilter newInstance(Context context) {
        return Utilities.getOverrideObject(AppFilter.class, context, 
           R.string.app_filter_class);
    }

    public boolean shouldShowApp(ComponentName app) {
        return !"com.google.android.gm".equals(app.getPackageName());
    }
}
```

Hope this help.